# how to use other class's attribute in a Python project

Tags: python, function, attributes, call

```py
import sys
import pygame

def check_event():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()


def update_screen(ai_setting, screen, ship):
    screen.fill(ai_setting.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The attribute `bg_color` and methods `flip()` and `blitme()` are from another `.py` file in the same directory.

But I do not understand how this `.py` file could use and call them without an `import`?

The code is from the book "Python Crash Course", page 248.

Comment: ***"use and call them without an 'import'?"***: You can't, you have to `import`.

Comment: Thanks stovfl, but the method blitme() and attribute 'bg_color' are from another two different py file called 'ship.py' and 'settings' respectively. But in this code file, there is no import, so I do not know how and why they can be called in the current file.

Comment: Add `import ship` and `import ai_setting`

Comment: your `blitme()` is part of object `ship` (`ship.blitme()`` which you send to this function as argument - `update_screen( ..., ship)`. So you don't use this directly - you don't use object from other file till you don't run function `update_screen`. You don't import `ship` to this file but you may import `update_screen()` to another file where you wil run `update_screen()` with argument `ship` from other file and `update_screen()` will get it.

Comment: the same is with `bg_color` which is part of object `ai_settings` - you don't access  directly from other file but you import `update_screen` to other file where you run it with `ai_setting` which exists in other file.

Comment: BTW: in this file `ship` is only local variable which may have the same name as object in other file but it is not the same object. You can use other name instead of `ship` in this file - ie. `hello_world` - and you will have `def update_screen(ai_setting, screen, hello_world):` and `hello_world.blitme()` - and it will works the same way.

Comment: Ah, yes. Your answer is correct, yes in the following code the update_screen() is called in another file. Understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def update_screen()` is only definition and Python doesn't check if variables in definition are correct. It will check variables when you execute this function. Besides `ship` in `update_screen()` is only local variable which you get as argument in `def update_screen(..., ship)` so you don't access directly `ship.blitme()` from other file.

I expect that you import this code to other file and in other file you execute it with instance of class `Ship` which definition you have in other file. And then Python will assign existing instances `Ship` to local variable `ship` inside `update_screen(..., ship)` and it will use methods `blitme()` from this instance.

The same is with `ai_settings` and `ai_setting.bg_color`.

---

As for `flip()` - you import `pygame` in this file and it imports `pygame.display` so you have direct access to `pygame.display.flip()` in this file.

Comment: That is exactly correct, yes in the following code update_screen() is called, and variable ship is created as an instance of the class Ship from and imported. Thanks a lot furas~!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are able to access the other variables and methods is because of `sys` module you are importing in the beginning.

Python comes with many modules available to import, and sys is one of them. The sys module is a set of functions that provide crucial information about how your Python script is interacting with the host system.

The sys modules has information about :

- What version of Python is running
- The path to the Python executable that is executing your script
- The command line options used to execute your script
- Any Python specific flags that have been set
- Information about floating point values and their representation.
- functions which can set what happens after each python instruction.
- and a function to cleanly exit the Python interpreter.

For more detailed info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Comment: thanks Parth, I think the method exit() is from sys, but the method 'blitme()' and attribute 'bg_color' are from another two different py file called 'ship.py' and 'settings' that I created. But in this code file, there is no import, so I do not know how and why they can be called in the current file